# My website got several unkown visits

Tags: websites

sorry if this question do not fit here.

I am at this moment making a website which is not finished at all.

I found some analytics for the site and found something strange.

I have 30 visits from USA, 8 from Germany, 1 from Russia and 1 from China. (I am Danish)

This site has not been published anywhere. Is it just a coincidence?

I am not worried about it, since I find it quite harmless. I'm just curious about who those people might could be.

Comment: They are most likely automated bots. You'll get tons more to come, so welcome to the Internet ;)

Comment: I have a website which receives about 50 hits a day, but every few weeks it receives a spike of about 2000 hits by about 300 different IPs. I have no idea what they are doing and why, but I am quite sure that they aren't human, because none of them performs an actual action on the website.

Answer (score 3):

Whether your site is unpublished or not makes little difference:

Web spiders (automated engines which index content on websites for search giants like Google and Yahoo) automatically crawl every site they can find through DNS records.

You will likely receive dozens, if not hundreds of these types of visits on a daily/weekly basis.